# What is the Iterable interface used for in Batch Apex?

Tags: apex, batch, iterable

I have start learning "Batch Apex" and have read much material about it. But I am unsure of the use of Iterable in batch apex. I have seen many confusing examples too.

I read this in the documentation, and am unsure of its meaning. Can anyone explain explain this in more detail?

> "Iterable is used when you need to create a complex scope for the batch job. You can also use the iterable to create your own custom process for iterating through the list."
>
> From [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Answer (score 11):

The most common use case I have seen is when you need to [batch over an aggregate query](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000192834&language=en_US). It's the only time I've needed to adopt this approach, anyway. The walkthrough has a pretty thorough example. The fun part is, you can implement all the related interfaces on the same class.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult>, Iterable<AggregateResult>, Iterator<AggregateResult>, Schedulable
{
    Integer index;
    List<AggregateResult> aggregates;
    public MyBatch()
    {
        index = 0;
        aggregates = [/*query*/];
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Iterator<AggregateResult> iterator()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public Boolean hasNext()
    {
        return index < aggregates.size();
    }
    public AggregateResult next()
    {
        return aggregates[index++];
    }
    public Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public  void  execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<AggregateResult> scope)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using SOSL with batchable also another common use of returning an Iterator from the start method? or is it not in general a good practice to do so?

Comment: I've never done it, so it seems like a rare use case. But that doesn't mean it's inappropriate to use in that scenario.

Answer (score 10):

If your logic is based on rows from an SObject then the `Database.QueryLocator` is the way to go as that allows the batchable to query very large numbers of records.

But sometimes you may want to do some work that isn't directly related to SObject rows. In that case the iterable object can simply be an array/list:

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<Execution> {

    private class Execution {
        // Various data fields go here
    }

    public Execution[] start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Execution[] execs = new Execution[] {};
        // Logic that creates and adds to the list
        // Subject to normal governor limits
        return execs;
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, Execution[] execs) {
        for (Execution exec : execs) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your leading advice. What are some reasons you would find the latter approach the right tool for the job?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Most batchables I've written use the `Database.QueryLocator` approach. The bit of code in the answer is from some recent work that passes a set of event Ids and the name of a listener class in the `Execution` object to ensure each listener gets its own set of governor limits. So I'd say only use the iterable approach where really necessary as its more complicated and harder to test.

Comment: @Adrianlarson I used an iterable once when using a CSV as input to the batch start. Iterable dealt with heap issues as it parsed the CSV file into chunks of 100 rows which were supplied to the execute() method