# Could we loop through an API response in Batch Apex rather than a soql result?

Tags: apex, rest-api, batch

I have been thinking if Batch Apex could be made to work with an API response rather than a soql query's result (which is usually the case).

Assume that we have a rest API that returns a JSON response that could be deserialized to a List of type custom apex class (`List<DeserializableClass>`), would we be able to loop through this deserialized List response in Batch Apex's execute method?

I found one interesting reply from @sfdcfox on the following post:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yXCIAY

Reading through that post, I got a feeling that this could be made possible, but I'm not quite sure how its done. Please do share your experience if you have done/tried this before.

P.S - this may be a silly question, but I had to ask anyway! :)

Comment: Why do you want batch specifically?

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I want to make some updates/inserts in a custom object based on the API's response. The updates/inserts could be around 14,000 - 15,000 records.

Comment: Look up iterable batch apex. Can't answer this one from my phone but the short answer is yes.

Comment: Related: [What is the Iterable interface used for in Batch Apex?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137443/what-is-the-iterable-interface-used-for-in-batch-apex/137448)

Comment: Its exactly what @sfdcfox pointed to in the post linked in the question. So I'd have to create a custom iterator that would be 
    global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<DeserializableClass?*>{
        public CustomIterable(){
        }
    }
Remember "DeserializableClass" is not a custom object, its an apex class just used to deserialize the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, since you're getting a list from your callout, you can just do this:

```
global class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<MyClass> {
    global class MyClass {
        // Whatever params you need here
    }
    global Iterable<MyClass> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return (Iterable<MyClass>)JSON.deserialize(getCalloutBody(), List<MyClass>.class);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, MyClass[] scope) {
        // Processing done here
   }
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
   }
}
```

This works because `List<X>` is also an `Iterable<X>`.

Comment: Fair enough. Good catch. Still sometimes miss the forest for the trees.

Comment: @sfdcfox - This is a lot simpler solution, and works great!
Just curious - is there any reason why you used MyClass[] rather than List<MyClass> in the execute method's param?

Comment: @James I prefer typing "case correct" even though Apex doesn't care, so `List<x>` is at least 10 keystrokes counting shift keys, but `x[]` is only 3 keystrokes. Every time I use the short syntax I save 1-2 seconds of typing. Additionally, there's a 3 million character limit for code per org, so I can replace 6 characters with 2, potentially reducing the code base by several kilobytes. I also find `[]` easier to read in long blocks of code. Finally, it's an old habit that *far* predates my use of Apex or even Java, back when I was still in school and learning the likes of C.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Wow! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the solution, and the cherry-on-top knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this no problem with an `Iterable`. Something like:

```
public class MyBatch
    implements Database.Batchable<MyClass>, Iterable<MyClass>, Iterator<MyClass>
{
    Integer index;
    List<MyClass> deserializedData;
    public MyBatch()
    {
        index = 0;
        deserializedData = JSON.deserialize(/*callout*/, List<MyClass>.class);
    }
    public Iterator<MyClass> iterator()
    {
        return this;
    }
    public Boolean hasNext()
    {
        return index < deserializedData.size();
    }
    public MyClass next()
    {
        return deserializedData[index++];
    }
    public Iterable<MyClass> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return this;
    }
    public  void  execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<MyClass> scope)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the valuable share.
Follow-up question: wouldn't the "next()" method's return type be MyClass rather than AggregateResult?

Comment: Yup. Copy-pasta. Almost got all of it.

Comment: That's *incredibly* more complicated than it needed to be...

Comment: @AdrianLarson See my answer.

Comment: I think calling it * incredibly* more complicated is somewhat hyperbolic, seeing how it's the same core solution. No need to be disparaging.